# getPassword() method returns everytime a different encrypted character array

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a login frame. I am saving the passwords in the database. The `getPassword()` method returns each time a new encrypted character array.

```
String pass = txtPass.getPassword().toString();
```

How to then compare the passwords stored in the database and the that given by the user ??

Comment: Which `getPassword` method?

Answer (score 6):

`JPasswordField.getPassword()` returns a char array. To create a String from the char array, you must use `new String(charArray)`. `toString()`, on any array, returns the type of the array followed by its hash code (something like `[C@39ea2de1`), and it's thus not a functionally interesting information.

Comment: There is a reason getPassword() returns a char array. Never store it in a String. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8881376/1666765 for a detailed explanation.